# How to read embedded Schema values in DD4T Java?

Tags: dd4t, java

We have a Schema like this:

SchemaChild of type Embedded with two fields; A (text) and B (text)

SchemaParent of type Content with one Field C (SchemaChild) as a multi-value field.

How can I iterate in DD4T Java to read all values and print in `<tr>` and `<td>`  tags?

Answer (score 3):

1. SchemaChild:

   > ```
   > private String fieldA;     
   > private String fieldB;
   > ```

Generate getters and setters.

2. SchemaParent

   `private List<SchemaChild> fieldC;`

again generate getter setter etc.

In view, read the values like:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${entity.fieldC}">
${item.fieldA}
${item.fieldB}
</c:forEach>
```

where entity points to SchemaParent